# how to filter view having three group with one or and two and group?

Tags: 7, views

I am having a view with three group filter i want to add condition like this

**Example Below:**

group1

field1 (and)
filed2

**AND**

group2

field1 (or)
filed2

**OR**

group3

field1 (or)
filed2

what issue i actually face is when i change the second and  third group filter to **AND** automatically the first and second group value is changing to **OR** how to solve this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For ease of use I would suggest looking at [Views Raw SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_raw_sql). While Views is a powerful query builder, it sometimes makes assumptions and in a general sense is designed to solve 80% of general types of listings and queries -- when implementing advanced logic, it can fail short.

Another option is to use the [Views API Hooks (hook_views_query_alter)](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) and alter the query using a small custom drupal module.